# Does javascript saves server's electricity?

Tags: javascript, client, server-side

I have heard that by putting more and more functionality to client device (via javascript) instead of processing them on server-side and sending to client actually saves the power.
Does it true ? Is it that significant to even bother ?

Comment: It is very unlikely to have a noticeable impact on your servers consumption of electricity. I'd go so far as to say it's unlikely to have any impact.

Comment: This question appears to be [off topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: It depends on what kind of calculation you want to be done client side. Basically there would not be a great difference except the calculations need a very high amount of the processing power or they have to use the GPU.

Comment: This is off-topic, but yes, it saves computing time and energy. However, there are 3 things to keep in mind :
1 - The impact is very (very) small
2 - You have to be careful : the client should not handle critical data (the server is always true, never trust the client)
3 - Depending on how you do this, you could involuntary increase the consumption of the server if you do this clumsily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory, if your server does less computations (ie. by pushing them to the client) you will require less power. How this works out in practice remains to be seen.

The effect is likely to be small; not big enough to base an architectural decision on. Unless you're Facebook or Google and you have massive datacenters all over the world it's probably not a good idea to *design* for power consumption.

Keep in mind that the computation you save on the server now has to be made by the client. The total amount of power required (by client and server) might actually increase. Also keep in mind the limited battery life of mobile devices.

Answer (score 0):

It depending on the work you're doing, the basic idea of that is some of the servers workload is putting in to the client, anyway since the biggest parts still on the server , electricity consumption not reducing in a considerable amount.